# clearTimeout does not work proberly

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

Here is my code:

```
 var timeout = 0;

function start() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 50) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            aRandomNumber1 = random();
            aRandomNumber2 = random();
            aRandomNumber3 = random();

            document.getElementById('field1').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber1] + '" alt="Bild1">';
            document.getElementById('field2').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber2] + '" alt="Bild2">';
            document.getElementById('field3').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber3] + '" alt="Bild3">';
        }, i);
    }

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = 0;
```

The images aren't stopping on this point. There should be changed at the next step.

Comment: You are overwriting timeout in each iteration, so your clearTimeout is only ever going to stop the very last one

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? You're only clearing the 1000th timeout, the rest will still work normally

Comment: After the last timeout, I'd like to change the image of the div..

Comment: `clearTimeout` is working exactly as expected.

Comment: okay, then how should I resolve that?

Comment: Please make it clear as to what you are trying to make, are you doing a slideshow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, this line:

```
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
```

Is simply re-creating a variable called timeout, not creating a new instance of it. When you CAN do, is make the timeout an object. Objects are functions that act as a "template" to create more instances of themselves, so you will actually have 1,000 different setTimeout functions.

```
var timeout = 0;
//Store all created functions
var functions = [];

function start() {
    //Create 1000 objects and store them in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        functions.push(new Timeout());
    }

    function Timeout() {
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            aRandomNumber1 = random();
            aRandomNumber2 = random();
            aRandomNumber3 = random();

            document.getElementById('field1').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber1] + '" alt="Bild1">';
            document.getElementById('field2').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber2] + '" alt="Bild2">';
            document.getElementById('field3').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber3] + '" alt="Bild3">';
            }, i);
        }
    }

for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
    functions[i].clearInterval(functions[i].timeout);
}

timeout = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the reference to `timeout` each iteration, so you are only having the reference to the last timeout stored. You can try to save all references to timeouts into an array e.g. `timeouts`, and after that loop through the array and clear each invoked timeout;

```
var timeouts = [];

function start() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 50) {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            aRandomNumber1 = random();
            aRandomNumber2 = random();
            aRandomNumber3 = random();

            document.getElementById('field1').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber1] + '" alt="Bild1">';
            document.getElementById('field2').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber2] + '" alt="Bild2">';
            document.getElementById('field3').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img[aRandomNumber3] + '" alt="Bild3">';
        }, i);
       timeouts.push(timeout);
    }
function clearTimeouts(){
   timeouts.forEach(timeout =>{ clearTimeout(timeout);});
   timeouts = [];
}
// stopping all timeouts after 1000 ms
setTimeout(clearTimeouts, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you so much, but now, the images aren't changing anymore

Comment: what do you mean? Once you stop all timeouts, nothing will be changing any more. And using this code, you stop everything immediately, so if you want to stop the images changing only after some time you need to call `clearTimeout` after some time as well, see updated answer